# How to print @<something> in php?

Tags: php, ssh, sed

I have a string, like this:

```
sed -i 's@<serverport>[0-9]\+</serverport>@<serverport>".self::$serverPort."</serverpot>@' ".self::$configFile
```

I want to send SSH command with this string. But if I try echo it the result will:

```
sed -i 's@[0-9]\+@7777@' /folder/to/server/mods/deathmatch/mtaserver.conf
```

How can I send the SSH command with the correct string?

Comment: Hmm. Just the echo wrong? If I send it to SSH it will be well?

Comment: You're just printing it out via PHP on a webpage. Which is why the things in angle `<brackets>` are not displayed. Use your browsers view source.

Comment: Or use `echo htmlentities($variable)`. That will translate the `<>` to `&lt;&gt;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're printing this on an HTML web page, the `<something>` is treated as a HTML tag. If you're echoing something that isn't HTML, but contains these special characters, you need to encode them so they'll be displayed instead of interpreted by the browser. Use `htmlentities()` for this:

```
echo htmlentities($command);
```